# Do I need an Internet connection to install Ubuntu Studio?

Tags: installation, ubuntu-studio

I am intending to dual Ubuntu studio with Vista (already on the computer). I am told by various online tutorials that I need an internet connection while installing Ubuntu Studio. I have installed the ISO file and burned it to a DVD. Does the installation process download more files for the OS and if so, how much?

Comment: Every ubuntu wants an internet connection to download any updates since the release of the iso. + If internet was needed, they could also have put more packages on that disk, its only 2,1 gb.

Comment: I don't know whether it's mandatory. I install ubuntu generally without internet (to reduce the install time, download at install time is really slow) and then update the system.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Are the updates just minor, <1gb downloads?

Comment: yeah, but I use ubuntu desktop not the studio version. So I don't know exactly.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu itself is an OS that heavily depends on a internet connection. All the repositories are on-line so installing software and updates are done over the internet. Our dash keeps getting things like webapps, internet searching (ie. amazon) and so on that all expect a permanent internet connection to get results.

During installation the system uses your installation media but can use the internet to update those files or install restricted software (like mp3 playback). Studio itself is aimed at the GNU/Linux audio, video and graphic and restricted formats are more than likely not available on the installation media (since it would be a copyright violation) so you will at least once need an internet connection for that. During that one time you can also update your system.

In short: yes you can install and use Ubuntu Studio without an internet connection but it is a lot easier if you do have one.